# Having issues with Regex expression, "not enough )'s" in C# statement

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex expression which I have sourced from a 3rd party. When I use it, I get a "not a enough )'s" error. Regex is not my strong point, although I cannot see anything obviously wrong.

code:

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection(); 
// Issue with following line
sc.Add(@"<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>");
foreach (string s in sc)  
{
   html = Regex.Replace(html, s, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  
}
return html;
```

Error:

```
parsing "<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>" - Not enough )'s.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I will just leave this here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/684117

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> <(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>

You're starting a second character with a ( and the other ) is in a character class.
Try:

```
<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|!\[)[^>]*?>
```

I've escaped the first [